# SQL Query rounding issue

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, sum, where-clause

I am using pyodbc to fetch total quantity of a product based on a certain criteria called "Strength". The "Strength" column also has string value for some records, so it is a `varchar` column.

The user enters details like brand, product type, product line, date range, minimum quantity (in this case, 12), and strength range

This is my query:

```
SELECT SUM(CAST([Qty] AS decimal(10, 2))) AS Qty 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        [Brand], 
        [ProdType], 
        [Lot], 
        CAST([Strength] AS DECIMAL(10,4)) AS [Strength], 
        [ProductLine], 
        [Size], 
        [Stage], 
        [Customer], 
        [PackedOn], 
        [Qty], 
        [RefreshedBy], 
        [RefreshedOn] 
    FROM SalesData 
    WHERE 
        (isnumeric([Strength]) = 1) 
        AND [Stage]='WIP' 
        AND [PackedOn]>='2018-06-03' 
        AND [PackedOn]<='2020-06-03' 
        AND [Brand]='ABC' 
        AND [ProductLine]='DEF' 
        AND [Size]='15' 
        AND [Qty]>='12.0' 
        AND [Strength]>=0.2 
        AND [Strength]<=0.4 
        AND [ProdType] Is Null
) as outputdata
```

This is my table:

```
ID  Brand   ProdType    Lot   Strength  ProductLine   Size    Stage   Province  PackedOn    Qty  

1   ABC     NULL      XXXXXXX     0.16       DEF       15        WIP    NULL    2018-12-07  1200
```

This is the create statement

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SalesData](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Brand] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [ProdType] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Lot] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Strength] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [ProductLine] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Size] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Stage] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Province] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [PackedOn] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Qty] [float] NOT NULL,
    [RefreshedBy] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [RefreshedOn] [varchar](max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

My problem is that this query results in a Quantity of 1200, even though it is outside the strength range. I am using SQL Server Management Studio V 18.4. How do I solve this?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with python or pyodbc. Please show table definition in the form of `CREATE TABLE`, including data types and enough sample data, in the form of `INSERT` statements, to reproduce the problem.

Comment: FYI SSMS is a client interface to get the version of your database engine use `select @@version`

Comment: Some general comments: Store numeric data in numeric formats; DO NOT store data as `VARCHAR( MAX )` unless your data is really that long, as performance will be poor for many reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your WHERE clause you should use.

`TRY_CAST([Strength] AS DECIMAL(10,4))>=0.2 AND TRY_CAST([Strength] AS DECIMAL(10,4))<=0.4`

Because sql queries start working from where clauses( and joins) then executes other parts. `SELECT` is the least important part and if you only use `CAST` in your select it will be only useful for printing data as your preferred format.

```
SELECT SUM(CAST([Qty] AS decimal(10, 2))) AS Qty FROM 
(SELECT [Brand], [ProdType], [Lot], CAST([Strength] AS DECIMAL(10,4)) AS [Strength], [ProductLine], [Size], [Stage], [Customer], [PackedOn], [Qty], [RefreshedBy], [RefreshedOn] 
FROM SalesData 
WHERE (isnumeric([Strength]) = 1) AND [Stage]='WIP' AND [PackedOn]>='2018-06-03' 
AND [PackedOn]<='2020-06-03' AND [Brand]='ABC' AND [ProductLine]='DEF' 
AND [Size]='15' AND [Qty]>='12.0' AND TRY_CAST([Strength] AS DECIMAL(10,4))>=0.2 AND TRY_CAST([Strength] AS DECIMAL(10,4))<=0.4 AND [ProdType] Is Null) as outputdata
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `CAST()` before doing numeric comparison, otherwise SQL Server compares strings, not numbers, which leads to unexpected results: as an example, string-wise, `'2'` is greater than `'12'` (since it starts with `'2'`, which is greater than `'1'`) That's true of all numeric comparisons involved in the query (`Size` is also concerned).

I would suggest `TRY_CAST()`, which avoids error and returns `null` if conversion fails (which will effectively fail the condition, and remove the corresponding row from the query).

Also, the subquery is unnecessary.

Consider:

```
SELECT SUM(Qty) Qty
FROM SalesData 
WHERE 
    Stage = 'WIP' 
    AND PackedOn >= '2018-06-03' 
    AND PackedOn <= '2020-06-03' 
    AND Brand = 'ABC' 
    AND ProductLine = 'DEF' 
    AND ProdType Is Null
    AND Qty >= 12
    AND TRY_CAST(Strength AS DECIMAL(10, 4)) >= 0.2
    AND TRY_CAST(Strength AS DECIMAL(10, 4)) <= 0.4 
    AND TRY_CAST(Size AS INT) = 15
```

If you want to cast your `float` output to `decimal`, it is more accurate to this after the `sum()`, so:

```
SELECT CAST(SUM(Qty) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) Qty
FROM ...
```